# circular dependency in dotnet core 2.0 console application using ServiceCollection

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm trying to setup a simple dependency injection using IServiceCollection that comes with Dotnet core 2.0 **Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection** nuget package. I am new to it so I started with a small experiment:

```
public interface IService
{
}

public class JobService : IService
{
    public IService m_service { get; set; }
    public JobService(IService service)
    {
        m_service = service;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IServiceCollection serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        ConfigureService(serviceCollection);
        var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
        //exception on next line
        var service = serviceProvider.GetService<App>();
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }

    private static void ConfigureService(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        serviceCollection.AddTransient<IService, JobService>();
        serviceCollection.AddTransient<App>();
    }
}
```

The above should register all types with the container but during runtime, I get :

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'A circular dependency was detected for the service of type 'TestCore.IService'.'

I don't see a circular dependency in my implementation. Can someone point out where this circular dependency comes from?

As for the service, it should be injected into this App class I made:

```
public class App
{
    private IService m_service;
    public App(IService service)
    {
        m_service = service;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dependency injection framework is unable to resolve the dependency for `IService` due to a circular dependency.
This arises from the fact that your implementation of `IService` (`JobService`) is itself dependent on an implementation of `IService` (i.e. itself). It would not be possible to instantiate JobService as it is dependent on itself. The DI framework recognizes this and throws the exception you are seeing.
In order to avoid this you would need to make `JobService` dependent on an implementation of a different interface:

```
public interface IService
{
}

public interface IAnotherService
{
}

public class JobService : IService
{
    public IAnotherService m_service { get; set; }
    public JobService(IAnotherService service)
    {
        m_service = service;
    }
}

public class AnotherService : IAnotherService
{
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IServiceCollection serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        ConfigureService(serviceCollection);
        var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
        //exception on next line
        var service = serviceProvider.GetService<App>();
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }

    private static void ConfigureService(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        serviceCollection.AddTransient<IAnotherService, AnotherService>();
        serviceCollection.AddTransient<IService, JobService>();
        serviceCollection.AddTransient<App>();
    }
}
```

**Edit/Aside:** If you were using Autofac you could use keep the `IService` dependency in `JobService` but provide different implementations using [Named and Keyed Services](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html).

Comment: No, that's not the problem. The OP's code for `IService` and `JobService` compile just fine as they are.

Comment: It is not a compilation error  that the OP is getting. Try it, the error will occur at runtime.

Comment: Are you saying that the DI is trying to inject `JobService` in to the constructor of `JobService`?

Comment: Yes (but as it is an invalid operation exception I'm guessing it is too clever to try that). Is there another explanation?

Comment: You should explain the DI error in your answer. It's just not clear at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! As I understand it, this error message also points to bad design. I just made the same example with Autofac and the same circular dependency message was show (though Autofac implements the Microsoft DI package so no surprise).

Comment: True. However, it looks like with autofac you could use the same interface but provide different implementations using [Named and Keyed Services](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html).